# Keyboard hides textfield in my UITableViewController, view not scrolling

Tags: interface, keyboard, scroll, uitableview

It's my first post, when i have a problem i always find the solution here, but now i'm really stuck.

I think that I've read all the posts related to this problem, but with no luck.

I have a table view controller which contains multiple custom cells, every cell have a textfield input inside. So the user start from the top, insert the first value, then hit "Apply" button on the keyboards custom toolbar, taking control of the next textbox.

The toolbar is showing but not working at the moment, but doesn't matter, because when i press enter on simulator, the next textbox becomes active.

The real problem is about the view that isn't scrolling! It scrolls when i select the firts textbox, then nothing.

I've searched everywhere, and unfortunately i'm working a lot and i don't have enough time to solve this problem by myself.

Maybe it's a stupid thing that i'm missing, i hope someone can help.

in the .h file :

```
@interface PaginaCalcoliController : UITableViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

every textbox is delegated to PaginaCalcoliController which is the view class.

I'm sorry for my english, i hope we can find a solution!

Answer (score 1):

I think, to do this is by setting "contentInset".
First replace your UITableviewController with UIViewController and add UITableview as subview and wire up the tableview,datasource and delegate 
then,
do like the this,
put this in view didload method.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:) 
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil]; 
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidDisappear:) name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];

}

-(void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{

    NSDictionary *info=[notification userInfo];
    NSValue *aValue=[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];

    CGRect keyBoardRect=[aValue CGRectValue];
    keyBoardRect=[self.view convertRect:keyBoardRect fromView:nil];
    CGFloat keyBoardTop=keyBoardRect.origin.y;

    tableView.contentInset=UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, keyBoardTop+50, 0);
}

-(void)keyboardDidDisappear:(NSNotification *)notification
{
 tableView.contentInset=UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 0, 10, 0);


}
```

Hope this will help... :)

Comment: how to make this animated

Comment: try putting animation block while setting contentInset

Comment: im gonna try and post back soon

Comment: [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        detailsTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, keyBoardTop-50, 0);
    }];
work perfectly

Comment: hello, sorry for not answering! I did manage the thing somehow .. When i work another time to that project i will check, and try your code! thanks ;)

Comment: Not a good idea to hardcode the animation time. The 0.25 is the default for the keyboard. Better to get the value as in:

  NSNumber *rate = notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey];

Answer (score 1):

Not a good idea to hardcode the animation time. The 0.25 is the default for the keyboard. Better to get the value as in:

```
 NSNumber *rate = notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey];
```